# Efficient Way to Replace / Lookup Tokens in a String

Tags: r, loops, stringr

I have a large vector `x` (`~200k` elements) where each element is a comma separated string. I have also a small lookup table `lkp`, which maps old strings to new strings. For the sake of this example, let's assume that this is simply a named vector.

What I want to do is:

1. I want to split each element in `x` into its tokens
2. Replace the tokens with the help of lkp
3. Remove duplicates from the replacement and sort

A rather straight forward implementation looks like this:

```r
library(stringr)
x <- c("a,b,c", "c", "b,c", "a,b")
lkp <- c(a = "A", b = "A", c = "B")

tokens <- str_split(x, fixed(","))
lapply(tokens, \(t) sort(unique(lkp[t])))

# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B"

# [[2]]
# [1] "B"

# [[3]]
# [1] "A" "B"

# [[4]]
# [1] "A"
```

I observed while `str_split` is super fast, `lapply` may take quite some time:

```r
library(tictoc)
xbig <- x[sample(length(x), 2e6, TRUE)]
tic("str_split")
tokens <- str_split(xbig, fixed(","))
toc()
# str_split: 0.89 sec elapsed

tic("lapply")
res <- lapply(tokens, \(t) sort(unique(lkp[t])))
toc()
# lapply: 60.33 sec elapsed
```

So I was wondering, whether there is smarter way of doing this taking advantage of vectorization?

If I drop the uniqueness and sort property a better way would be

```r
tic("split")
res <- split(lkp[unlist(tokens)], rep(seq_along(tokens), lengths(tokens)))
toc()
# split: 2.89 sec elapsed
```

So I was wondering (given the super fast speed of `str_split`) whether there is maybe a `regex` solution which could benefit from `stringr`'s speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

1. `str_replace_all` to leverage the named vector `lkp` to do inplace replacement.
2. split the data on comma using `str_split`.
3. Get unique values.

```
library(stringr)
library(tictoc)


lapply(str_split(str_replace_all(x, lkp), fixed(",")), unique)

#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B"

#[[2]]
#[1] "B"

#[[3]]
#[1] "A" "B"

#[[4]]
#[1] "A"
```

On bigger vector.

```
tic("str_replace_all")
step1 <- str_replace_all(xbig, lkp)
toc()

#str_replace_all: 1.288 sec elapsed

tic("str_split")
step2 <- str_split(step1, fixed(","))
toc()

#str_split: 1.328 sec elapsed

tic("unique")
step3 <- lapply(step2, unique)
toc()
#unique: 5.955 sec elapsed
```

The timing is better than what you currently have but I think step 2 and 3 can be solved in 1 step without splitting the string using regex but can't come up with suitable regex right now.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines but thought that the OP's intent in tokenization is to not allow substring replacement (`"aa"` distinct from `"a"`), can the `str_replace_all` method be modified to include boundaries (comma, `^|$`)?

Comment: +1 thanks for the pointer. Actually I was toying with `str_replace_all` too, but the problem is that some tokens are "overlapping":, e.g. `x <- "aa,a"` with a lookup of `c(a ="C", aa = "B")`.

Comment: I guess we have to be smart regarding the order in `lkp`. Compare: `str_replace_all("a,aa", c(a="X", aa="Y"))` with `str_replace_all("a,aa", c(aa="Y", a="X"))`. The latter would be the intended behavior. So maybe a simple `sort(lkp, decreasing = TRUE)` would do?

Comment: have you considered converting `x` or `xbig` to a data.table, and using a join to get the values from `lkp`?  It would be pretty fast, but only really more efficient if you are okay with a frame as your output, rather than a list.

Comment: `data.table` would be an option, however, in my real scenario I am working with columns in a `tibble` so I'd prefere a solution on vectors, which I could simply plug in to my `tidyverse` workflow.

Comment: i think if you are already working with a frame, going with a join to look up would be ideal, and super fast; of course if speed is your objective, you'd probably want to (at least temporarily) move to data.table